# Filtering issue with Django, MySQL, and JSONField

Tags: json, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I'm troubleshooting filtering my model inside of Django.  I'm also using the django_mysql JSONField fieldtype for all of my 'categories' for a field inside of my modal.

```
class Image(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Image"
        verbose_name_plural = "Images"

    image = models.ImageField(verbose_name="Image Asset", upload_to='assets/images/', blank=True, null=True)
    is_published = models.BooleanField(verbose_name="Is this asset published", default=True, null=False)
    meta_format = models.CharField(verbose_name="Meta Format", max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    meta_width = models.CharField(verbose_name="Meta Width", max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    meta_height = models.CharField(verbose_name="Meta Height", max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    categories = JSONField(default=list)
```

For reference, categories is the field that i'm attempting to filter.

Lets say that I have this entry in my feed:

```
{
    "id": 18,
    "url": "http://localhost:8001/images/18/",
    "image": "https://cdn.test.com/assets/images/person.jpg",
    "is_published": false,
    "meta_format": "JPEG",
    "meta_width": "1466",
    "meta_height": "800",
    "categories": "[{\"category\": \"staff_gallery\"}]"
}
```

The only thing that will return this result is

```
>>> ImageAsset.objects.filter(categories="[{\"category\": \"staff_gallery\"}]")
```

And this isn't feasable, because there will most likely be more than one category.  If the entry changes to `"categories": "[{\"category\": \"staff_gallery\"},{\"category\": \"test\"}]"` then the whole query returns nothing.

One way around this was to turn it into just a list, or array... so essentially the category above would turn to `"categories": "[\"staff_gallery\"]"`.  By doing this, the following query WILL work and returns my query that I want.

```
>>> ImageAsset.objects.filter(categories__contains="[\"staff_gallery\"]")
```

But ... when I change the entry to `"categories": "[\"staff_gallery\",\"test\"]"` the query stops working unless I specify that string exactly (`"[\"staff_gallery\",\"test\"]"`) inside of the query.

This categories field was initially a data field that I was storing more than just this inside of it, but given the issues i'm having i've converted it to just a categories field.  My problem is if I can't figure this out i'm going to switch it to a char field and just search within it.  I thought these JSON fields were supposed to be more future forward and easy to use... but i'm finding that this isn't the case.

TL;DR: Filtering (as documented) isn't working.  JSON file filtering isn't working on anything but an exact match of the field contents.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the [JSONField documentation](https://django-mysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/model_fields/json_field.html#exact-lookups) there are specific lookups to query a JSONField.

For example, if you wanted to get images of the category "staff_gallery", you would have to use the following:

```py
ImageAsset.objects.filter(categories={'category': 'staff_gallery'})
```

Check the link above for further details.

Comment: Yeah that still doesn't work for me... which is part of my problem.
>>> ImageAsset.objects.filter(categories={'category': 'staff_gallery'})
<QuerySet []>

Comment: I think your problem might be that you are storing a string inside your JSONField, make sure you are passing a dictionary to the `categories` field instead of a string when you create an object

Comment: I'd have to agree with you, but no matter what I do I cannot change the fact that it's storing as a string, no matter how I store it.  I have other JSON fields that are NOT behaving the same, so i'm kind of confused at this point.

Comment: Looking at the entry you provided seems that the feed gives you `categories` as string already, did you try to parse it before assigning it to your model? Something like: `image_asset.categories = json.loads(feed_entry['categories'])`